# React Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '_internalPath' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to get firebase working with react, and got this error

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

export default function CoursesPage(){
    const [courses, setCourses] = useState(<p>Loading courses...</p>)
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetch(){
            const db = firebase.firestore()
            const myAuthLevel = (firebase.auth().currentUser != null) ? await (await db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()).data().authLevel : 0
            console.log(myAuthLevel)
            const courses = await db.collection("courses").where(myAuthLevel, '>=', 'authLevel').get()// orderBy('createdAt').get()
            console.log(courses)
        }
        fetch()
    },[])

    return(
        <page>
            <h1>Courses</h1>
            {courses}
        </page>
    )
}
```

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '_internalPath' of undefined
> fetch
> D:/User/Programming/node/coursewebpage/src/components/CoursesPage.js:12
> 9 |     const db = firebase.firestore()
> 10 |     const myAuthLevel = (firebase.auth().currentUser != null) ? await (await db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()).data().authLevel : 0
> 11 |     console.log(myAuthLevel)
> 12 |     const courses = await db.collection("courses").where(myAuthLevel, '>=', 'authLevel').get()// orderBy('createdAt').get()
> | ^  13 |     console.log(courses)
> 14 | }
> 15 | //const courses = await getFirebase().firestore().collection('courses').get()

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because something is going wrong either in query or auth and an unexpected state occurs since your app can't resolve the promise in your `fetch` function, wrap all your code of this function around a `try/catch` you will likely get a different error which will be more helpful than the one you are getting know. So do this:

```
async function fetch(){
    try {
        const db = firebase.firestore()
        const myAuthLevel = (firebase.auth().currentUser != null) ? await (await db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()).data().authLevel : 0
        console.log(myAuthLevel)
        const courses = await db.collection("courses").where(myAuthLevel, '>=', 'authLevel').get()// orderBy('createdAt').get()
        console.log(courses)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but the error remains the same (`Cannot read '_internalPath' of undefined`).

Comment: Try moving the `fetch` function out of your use effect and when calling it do so by `await fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

**update where() function:**

```
where('authLevel','<=',myAuthLevel)
```