# Querying firestore database returns "TypeError: Cannot read property '_internalPath' of undefined" as an error in console

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get firestore to work with my node.js server, however it keeps returning this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_internalPath' of undefined
> at fieldPathFromArgument (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:21877:30)
> at where (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:22246:19)
> at searchUsername (.\CS_Project\Source\server.js:54:33)
> at .\CS_Project\Source\server.js:78:19
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at .\CS_Project\Source\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (.\CS_Project\Source\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

I Believe that the issue is with the below function however I am still relatively new to using Node.js so it may be an issue elsewhere in my code.

```
async function searchUsername(username){
    try{
        const q = query(userDb, where("username" == username));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
};
```

The closest question I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66950980/react-unhandled-rejection-typeerror-cannot-read-property-internalpath-of-u), however when I tried their solution it didn't work.
The below error and code is from implementing the commented solution by @Dharmaraj.

> const q = query(userDb, where("username", ==, username));
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '==' at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

```
async function searchUsername(username){
    try{
        const q = query(userDb, where("username", ==, username));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try adding the commas in where clause: `where("username", ==, username)`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Just tried it and that returns a syntax error instead.

Comment: Forgot the quotes around `=`. It should be `where("username", "==", username)`